# Open Jupyter Notebooks with Opera on Mac

Tags: jupyter-notebook, opera

As per guidelines, I first generate config which I modify the `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` file updating default browser as :

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = '/Applications/Opera.app'
```

When running jupyter notebooks, I get the output `No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.`.

I have validated the opera app works, simply by running `open /Applications/Opera.app`.

Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling about, I managed to solve it by passing in the open command as the parameter:

```
'open -a /Applications/Opera.app %s'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my situation. My use case is that I'm using Jupyter LAB not notebook. So I had to pay attention to two things.

1. Pay attention to using "lab" in the --generate-config

   jupyter lab --generate-config
2. The jupyter_lab_config.py file in ~/.jupyter folder uses a different browser line than notebook:

   "c.ServerApp.browser"

then complete as follows:

```
c.ServerApp.browser = 'open -a /Applications/Opera.app %s'
```

I also removed the # and all tabs/indents/spaces before the #