# Problem opening Jupiter "lab" (not Jupiter notebook) specifically with the Opera browser parameter macOS

Tags: macos, jupyter, opera, jupyter-lab

Does anybody know how to successfully pass "Opera" parameter/argument when opening Jupyter Lab from macOS Terminal?

```
jupyter lab --browser=opera
```

I tried the above command and the output throws an error saying it could not find a web browser. If I use "jupyter lab --browser=safari" it works just fine.

Also, respectfully I am not interested in the other workaround to use c.NotebookApp.browser in the --generate-config as I've spent hours on that possible solution and it is not working with Opera no matter how I slice it (see my comment here: [Open Jupyter Notebooks with Opera on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117095/open-jupyter-notebooks-with-opera-on-mac/69917891#69917891))

Answer (score 0):

From what I tried out on my own, the `--browser` and its equivalent `--ServerApp.browser` flags are currently available only for 3 browsers: Chrome, Firefox, and Safari (I don't use Opera; but doing the same test for Microsoft Edge yields the same result, even though it uses the  same engine Chrome does). So, you can either ask for this feature on their GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab), or simply use `--no-browser` and copy the resulting link into Opera.

P.S: I even tried out `--generate-config`, and it probably has the same limitation as `--browser`, Opera is simply unsupported for this type of operation.